# Bootstrap 3 nav drop-down center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am customizing a menu in Bootstrap 3 and I am unsure how to center the drop down box in relation to the parent.

Here is an image to explain what I want to do - http://i.picpar.com/MBw.png

Here's a jsbin - http://jsbin.com/oCorUjA/1/

Thanks!

edit: Can anybody help me? I've tried many things and haven't made any progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I did was give each dropdown menu it's own ID, then I would define the element in CSS,...what you are trying to do essentially is this:

Don't overwrite the core bootstrap CSS first of all... but in Google Chrome, inspect the element, when you find dropdown menu add a margin-left: -35px; and you see that your first dropdown will line up in the center, so?... That should give you an idea on what you need to do for each dropdown menu with it's own ID :-)
You probably don't want to use negative margins, I'm just giving you an idea on what to do:

I personally gave each dropdown it's own Column ID and added the proper CSS to align it exactly in the center like you wanted...
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set the min-width to 160px for the dropdown menus (the ones that toggle when you hover over it). They are set to float:left and will always be 160px width, but the navbar width above is based on the length of the words you typed (servers, managed services, etc.). You can fix this by changing (.dropdown-menu) css position to relative instead of absolute. This will cause the navbar to bounce around as you hover over the items unless you then also set (.navbar-nav li a) to min-width 160px as well. I recommend using firefox as your browser so you can inspect the elements, make temporary css changes to see differences, and check mobile responsiveness. Best of luck